# Sticky header leave big space on breakpoint

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am kinda stuck with my code on a sticky header.

The header will shrink if it hit 770px point. But this cause me some problem when i try to do it on a browser on testing. Try load the page in a full size browser(>770) and shrink it to (<770) then scroll , it will leave me a space.

Is there any way to eliminate it ?

If you open in a small size (<770) and enlarge it (>770) when you scroll , the content will be covered by the headbar.

How do I modify my script to shrink up when I stop, and when i scroll down it come down again. (Like the facebook apps status bar)

My HTML

```
<div id="head"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

MY CSS

```
        body
        {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
            #head
            {
                width:100%;
                height:100px;
                background:blue;
                opacity: 0.5;
                float:left;             

            }
            #content
            {
                width:100%;
                height:5000px;
                background:yellow;
                float:left;
            }
            .fix
            {
                position:fixed;
                top:0;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
            @media (max-width:770px)
            {
                #head
                {
                    height:50px;
                }
            }
```

MY SCRIPT

```
var
    $win = $(window),
    $filter = $('#head'),
    $filterSpacer = $('<div />', {
      "class": "filter-drop-spacer",
      "height": $filter.outerHeight()
    });



  $win.scroll(function(){     
    if(!$filter.hasClass('fix') && $win.scrollTop() > $filter.offset().top){
      $filter.before($filterSpacer);
      $filter.addClass("fix");


    } else if ($filter.hasClass('fix')  && $win.scrollTop() < $filterSpacer.offset().top){
      $filter.removeClass("fix");
      $filterSpacer.remove();

    }
  });
```

Comment: @haxxxton Don't leave edit summaries in the question; that's what the edit summary field is for. Summarising your edit in the question body itself is littering.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs the edit only required a single line break to be added, and stackexchange post edits require a minimum of 6 characters to be changed.. would love to have left it without making more changes

Comment: @haxxxton there was and still is plenty more room for improvement; the idea of that 6 character limit is to push you to take a look at what else needs to be improved.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs it wasnt a case of 'improving' the question so much as making it functionally readable. (the html code wasnt displaying, which would have either prompted questions for it or potentially held up answers) i fully appreciate the limitation. I was merely explaining why it was necessary for me to add something outside of what was needed. in retrospect i could have re-edited my edit to remove the 6+ characters of my edit summary.. but was busy providing actual answers. thank you for your vigilance however

Comment: @haxxxton when you're making a question functional like that, part of your obligation is to find further ways to improve the question. that's why we have a 'too minor' rejection reason on suggested edits. I completely appreciate providing the indentation, but I'm pointing out you did have other means you could've taken to reach the small edit minimum.

Answer (score 1):

parts 1) and 2) can be solved with the following:

you need to update the height of your head upon window resize.

```
$win.resize(function(){
      $filterSpacer.outerHeight($filter.outerHeight());
});
```

you can check out a jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/k7utG/

however, as some browsers trigger this every pixel that a person changes during a resize event, perhaps look at putting some kind of limiter in there like Ben Alman's throttle / debounce plugin http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

as for the shrink/unshrink in part 3)

i would suggest using a timeout to trigger this

have a look at this expanded fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k7utG/2/

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem upon adding the win.resize :(

Comment: sorry i just read your part 3).. i only solved 1) and 2).. give me a sec

Comment: 1) 2) not sure the win.resize how it works. added into my code but the white space is still there :(

Comment: @user3418336 please update the jsfiddle to include more of your working code then please, as the jsfiddle i provided appears to solve this issue given the constraints and code you have currently provided

Comment: i copied the same thing into my page and the problem still exist :(

Comment: @user3418336 does it appear to be working on jsFiddle for you? do you have a live example link that you can post?

Comment: @haxxton i have found out the problem , i don't know how to code conflict with it. Because when i put in jquery 1.11.0 the filterSpacer work but the scroll bar doesn't stick to the top. If i change back to 1.7.2 den my scroll bar stick but the filterSpacer doesn't work

Comment: @user3418336 if you go into my fiddle and change the jquery version to either of the two you listed it still works. Your conflict must be coming from somewhere else in your code

Comment: just realise it is not the version of the code, don't know what is conflicting it :(